# How to assign indexed array values to multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'd like to replace the values of a multidimensional array with the values of a simple numerically indexed array. The number of values in each array is equal, but they do not have the same keys/indexes due to different array structure.

I had a working solution using `array_combine`, iteration, and a hashtable but cannot recreate my work. I've tried `array_merge`, `array_combine`, and looping through the arrays.

```
$venue_ids = array( 
    0 => array(
        0 => 2476 ), 
        1 => array( 
            0 => 2482,
            1 => 2480,
            2 => 2463 ),
        2 => array( 
            0 => 2484,
            1 => 2476,
            2 => 2486,
            3 => 2463 ));

$names = array( 
    0 => 'clubhouse',
    1 => 'campground',
    2 => 'lake',
    3 => 'range',
    4 => 'trfields',
    5 => 'clubhouse',
    6 => 'trfields',
    7 => 'range' );
```

I'd like the result to keep the structure of the first array, and simply substitute its values with those from the second. It should look like this:

```
$venues = array( 
    0 => array( 
        0 => 'clubhouse' ), 
    1 => array( 
        0 => 'campground',
        1 => 'lake',
        2 => 'range' ),
    2 => array( 
        0 => 'trfields',
        1 => 'clubhouse',
        2 => 'trfields',
        3 => 'range' ));
```

The configuration of `$venue_ids` will change, including the number of indexes and number of keys/values therein, but there will always be a matching 1-to-1 number of `$names`. I'd be happy just replacing values or constructing a whole new array matching the structure of `$venues_id` and working with that.

Comment: This "problem" seems to be the result of bad programming. I wonder how you got `$names` to nicely match up with the ids in `$venue_ids`? I know you want us to just to solve this problem, no questions asked, but I had to ask.

Comment: Undoubtedly!  Ended up where I am from a SQL query that gave me post_ids, and then a meta_query for the rest of the information from linked post types and taxonomies.  The original output was, among other things, the post_id of each of the venues (a custom post type).  The only way I could figure to get those numbers back through the database and get matching post_titles was to foreach the heck out of the meta_query and distill it into a simple array of post_ids for that key.  I'm sure that's where I went wrong, but couldn't figure out how to get the results without breaking the array down.

Comment: If you can't lay hold on your **working solution**, at least provide us your attempt to **recreate your work**.

Comment: I'm sure it is difficult. However, if you can get the ids of the venues from the database, can't you then also not get the names of the venues from the database? Thereby creating the array you want directly from the database?

Comment: Agree completely!  I'm having to manipulate relevant, but useless, data to get what I want when it's probably sitting right next door.  There is certainly a way to avoid getting to where I'm at, but I can only think to write a custom query that gets different results than get_post_meta... or more likely, figure out how to run the values through get_posts or get_the_title when they are still sitting in the original array.  Had I asked that when I first ran into trouble I'd have fewer bruises on my forehead, but sometimes it's easy to keep going down the rabbit hole once you get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably ask a new question about the queries to see if you can get the correct result to begin with, but in the meantime you can use `array_walk_recursive` to substitute the values:

```
array_walk_recursive($venue_ids, function (&$v) use (&$names) { $v = array_shift($names); });
print_r($venue_ids);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => clubhouse
        )    
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => campground
            [1] => lake
            [2] => range
        )    
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => trfields
            [1] => clubhouse
            [2] => trfields
            [3] => range
        )    
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/Wc3eL)

Comment: Agreed on the original query, but thank you for the solution regardless!  And if that is THE way to do it I'm very glad I asked, because it's not anywhere close to what I've been tinkering with.
ETA:  Needless to say, it works perfectly.  Thank you!

Comment: @fxrgc You can still accept this answer as the best one, that is as good as a +1 vote. PS: If you don't understand why this answer does what it does, then you should ask.

Comment: Asking what I thought was a well-worded question got me a -1 already, probably for not providing the hundreds of lines of commented attempts at a solution riddled with four-letter variable names I'd have to edit to make suitable for work.  But frankly the code provided is completely foreign to me, and I'm very curious how and why it works and why the dozens of searches I tried doing didn't lead me to that function, but I wouldn't know where to start since I can't yet read what I assume is php shorthand in that code.

Comment: @fxrgc: You can look up [array_walk_recursive()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) in the manual. It uses a callback function to go through the provided array recursively. That [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) gets the array entry [by reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), hence the `&` in front of the `$v`. That basically means, in this case, that the function can alter the original. Then `array_shift()` eats entries of the beginning of `$names` and puts them in `$venue_ids`.

Comment: @fxrgc sorry I wasn't around to offer an explanation of the code, I think KIKO gave a pretty good one. If you still have questions please comment again.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware thanks for the explanation in my absence. I'll pay it back elsewhere...